# If statements - certain value or more

Tags: objective-c

I have an app where i want it to only do some thing if the int value is a certain number or above and i cant seem to figure out how to do it, i can do it if it is exactly the amount but not if its more.

For example i have an int value of 0 and its goes up every time you push a button, when it becomes 20 or higher i want it to do something when another button is pressed.

Thanks for he help!

```
- (IBAction)storeTroll:(id)sender {
    if (count == 20) {
        trollButton.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean `if(count>=20) {...}`?

Answer (score 3):

```
Operator    Description
x == y  Returns true if x is equal to y
x > y   Returns true if x is greater than y
x >= y  Returns true if x is greater than or equal to y
x < y   Returns true if x is less than y
x <= y  Returns true if x is less than or equal to y
x != y  Returns true if x is not equal to y
```

So, use >= :

```
- (IBAction)storeTroll:(id)sender {
    if (count >= 20) {
        trollButton.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```